# How to create and use bundles in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, bundle

I have an application that I wrote that uses an external unix executable file. It needs to run this file in order to get some data needed for further processes.

Right now this executable is located in my project folder and in order to use it in my app I have hardcoded paths to it (which is bad).

I've heard that to avoid this hardcoded paths issue it's possible to use bundles.

Can anyone explain me if this is the best way to achieve what I want, and direct me how to do it if so?!

I already looked through similar questions on stackoverflow and went through this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i

it didn't really help me so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the NSBundle object to locate your executable.  You start by getting your application's bundle using `[NSBundle mainBundle]`.  Depending on where you've placed your Unix tool, you can use NSFundle's `pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:` or `pathForResource:ofType:` to locate your executable.

For example, if your Unix tool is in your Application bundle's Resources folder, you could do the following:

```
 NSString* toolPath = [[NSBundle mainBunble] pathForResource:@"toolname" ofType:nil]
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. I have a quick question though...what do you mean by "Application bundle's Resources folder"?

Comment: When you build a Mac OS X application, Xcode creates a bundle for you.  One of the folders contained within the application's bundle is AppName.app/Contents/Resources where images, and other resources are stored.  You can put anything in there that your application needs to use while it is running.  See [Apple's Bundle Structure Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1)